# How do I make a file download require a username and password

Tags: html, download, password-protection

In a basic HTML web page, how do you make the user have to enter a username and password before they are allowed to download a file?

What is the best way of achieving this on a website, preferably in plain HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with plain HTML. Easiest way is probably to place the protected file in a directory protected by an .htaccess and .htpasswd file.

Comment: Is this something that can be achieved using a commercial web host?

Comment: Mosts hosts should have a way to do this in the admin control panel. Check the FAQs or email your host for support. If you're using cPanel, there's a very easy way of adding a password-protected directory.

Comment: What are the general risks of making files available in this way?  Could sophisticated hackers get hold of the file anyway?

Comment: A brute force attack (randomly guessing words at a high speed), or if a hacker gets a hold of your account password, a person with privileged access to your server host's computers....all possibilities, somewhat unlikely to happen, but hey, that's the risk of putting anything online.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be achieved in HTML.

With client side technologies, the best you are likely to be able to achieve is a JavaScript prompt that you use the data from to direct people to a secret URI.

This is something that really should be [handled by the web server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html#introduction).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with David...this can't really be done.  Putting up a JavaScript prompt only protects you so far as well...that isn't really secure.

If you are on an Apache server, you could setup a .htaccess file and setup some user authorization options that point at a page which has the link to your download file.  A simple implementation would give you 1 user/password combo that you could distribute to your users.  The Apache documentation for this may be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/howto/htaccess.html).  Unfortunately I'm not really familiar with how IIS handles this sort of thing.

If you don't want to distribute a generic username/password combo to your users, you're pretty much going to be stuck creating a (or making use of an exsitng) user-management system.  There are quite a few modules strewn throughout the web, and a simple Google search should bring you to quite a number of tutorials or existing implementations, depending on what you require.

Answer (score -1):

first download phpmyadmin.open the file.click on create login.name it as login.php.then create a new want again name file.php.after you click yes it popout a logon information.enter the usrname you want and password you want

hope this help!